# how can i call & fill function 2d parameter inline?

Tags: c#, function, delegates, inline

i have the following function which has 2D array

```
public string StoredProcedure(Func<string[,]> StoredProcedureParameterFunc)
{
   string[,] StoredProcedureParameter = StoredProcedureParameterFunc();
   return StoredProcedureParameter.Length.ToString();
}
```

i call it as follows

```
public string test_Selecting()
{
   string x =StoredProcedure(delegate {string[,] a = new string[,] 
   {{"ant","aunt"},{"Sam","Samantha"},{"clozapine","quetiapine"}}; return a;});
   return x;
}
```

i need more simple way to call and fill 2D list or 2D array **inline**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Func` delegate as follows:

```
public string StoredProcedure(Func<string[,]> StoredProcedureParameterFunc)
{
    string[,] StoredProcedureParameter = StoredProcedureParameterFunc();
    return StoredProcedureParameter.Length.ToString();
}

...

StoredProcedure(() => new string[,] { { "ant", "aunt" }, { "Sam", "Samantha" }, { "clozapine", "quetiapine" } });
```